# How to clear contents of a collection at the end of the session?

Tags: asp.net, session, web-applications

I am designing a Cart Application using ASP.NET. When a user finishes his shopping the total payable amount is displayed. Then he closes the browser. Next time when the browser is opened the quantity of the items still remains unchanged and when the an item is selected the old quantity is displayed.

It is probably because the ASP.NET Development Server is in the running state and is displayed  in the notification area.

The code for Check-Out button that I am using is as follows.

```
    protected void btnCheckout_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<CD> CdCheckOutList = new List<CD>();
            CdCheckOutList = (List<CD>)Session["cart"];
            double totalPrice = 0.0;

            foreach (var cd in CdCheckOutList)
            {
                totalPrice += cd.Amount;
            }
            lblTotal.Text = "Total Price = "+totalPrice.ToString();

    }
```

Please help me tackle the problem.

Answer (score 0):

At the end of the checkout process you have two options:

Remove just the `cart` item from `Session`, like this:

```
Session.Remove("cart");
```

Keep the `cart` key in `Session`, but make the value null, like this:

```
Session["cart"] = null;
```

As for when the user clicks the close button on the browser, then I defer to a previous StackOverflow question for [javascript detect browser close tab/close browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3888902/javascript-detect-browser-close-tab-close-browser)

Answer (score 0):

The call from onunload event will sort it out your problem. Take a look at the below piece of code which will help you.

Code Behind:

```
public static void ClearSession()
{ 
    Session["cart"] = null;
}
```

Jquery and Ajax call to the server side call:

```
$(window).unload(function() {

 $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "PageName.aspx/ClearSession",
    data: "{}",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(msg) {
         // Do something interesting here.
    }
});
```